Does Google Speech-To-Text service supports OGG_OPUS or WEBM_OPUS for realtime streaming recognize?
I was able to get it working with LINEAR16 encoding, but can't with OGG_OPUS. So question is, is it really supported? I didn't find any related information in docs unfortunately.

Hi @rsatom, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

@NithishKumarRamisetty it's already there https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/369724753

Funny, my issue on tracker was closed without offering any solution. So I decided just switch to Amazon Transcribe...
